# Mount remote file system using sshfs with a PHP script

Tags: php, linux, sshfs

I want my PHP script can mont a remote system with sshfs command.
But it doesn't seem to work, the folder has been created but the folder still empty after execution. I also tried with a user without SU and it was working fine.

```php
mkdir ("/var/mont/remote/");
$cmd = "sshfs -o password_stdin -o allow_other enzo@192.168.0.29:/home/enzo/remote/ /var/mont/remote/ <<< 'MyRemotePassword'";
$output = nl2br(shell_exec($cmd));
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

This script (test.sh) should work :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
php -r 'mkdir ("/var/mont/remote");
        $cmd = "sshfs -o password_stdin -o allow_other enzo@192.168.0.29:/home/enzo/remote/ /var/mont/remote/ <<< 'MyRemotePassword'";
        $output = nl2br(shell_exec($cmd));
        echo $output;'
```

Run it as `bash test.sh`

Comment: How exactly should I do? I create a php file and I paste that ?